# Xamarin Application Error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

So, I created a new project in Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015 and when I run the pre-built app with the text "Welcome to Xamarin forms" I get these errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.    Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorPrimaryDark'.   Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorPrimary'.   Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowActionBar'.    Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowNoTitle'.  Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 2
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.    Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 3
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'colorAccent'.    Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 4
>   Error     Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.   Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 4
>   Error     No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'windowActionModeOverlay'.    Hello.Droid C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml 4

Can someone help me with these errors?

Comment: I guess the main problem is that a Theme is not found. It this really the default prebuilt app ?

Comment: @FelixD. Yeah, It's the prebuilt app when I create the project

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080323/no-resource-found-that-mach-the-given-name-theme-appcompat-light-noactionbar

Comment: @FelixD. I downloaded that package. Still having the same errors

Comment: have you checked if the files existed in windows explorer ? `C:\Users\Bogdan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Hello\Hello\Hello.Droid\Resources\values\styles.xml`

Comment: With what SDK are you compiling, I had similiar errors but after I installed JDK 8 and Compiled with latest SDK all worked

Comment: @FelixD. How can I check that ? I put the package in C:\Users\Bogdan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Hello\packages

Comment: In VS Right click on the project Properties, under Application look for 'Compile using Android Version'

Comment: @DonaldJansen [SDK](http://imgur.com/jbvbB2p). Check this out

Comment: Im building with Nougat, let me check if I can compile with Marshmellow

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using (check under nuget)

Comment: @DonaldJansen I am using 2.2.0.45

Comment: Ok I want you to try update it to the latest one, and using SDK Manager install Nougat. I had this problem with 2.1.0.6529 but that was a long time ago.

Comment: Another thing I want you to check is, Tools > Options > Scroll down to Xamarin and expand it select Other and check if you are using the latest Xamarin for Visual Studio